# Angular2 : Rerender component when there is a change for inner property of an object

Tags: angular

After modifying the inner property of an object as below

```
delete this.siteConfig.sites[siteKey].serverIpWhitelist[ip];
```

The list bind with `ngFor` is not updated.

I tried `NgZone.run()` and `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, neither works.

The only way I found to update the list is adding the following line

```
this.siteConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.siteConfig));
```

Quite stupid, is there any other manner to force rerender the component?

---

UPDATE:

The ngFor loops the property of an object via `KeysPipe`

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

And the `ngFor` looks like `*ngFor="let pair of (siteConfig.sites | keys)"`

Comment: `this.siteConfig = this.siteConfig.slice()` should do as well. `*ngFor` checks for array content changes therefore I guess we need more details to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: `siteConfig` is not an `Array`,  it is an object,  the `ngFor` works with it via a pipe converting the object to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your pipe impure.

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys', pure: false})
```

This way the pipe is called every time change detection runs, no matter if something changed or not. You should ensure the pipe works efficient because this way it's call very often.

Comment: seems it is not efficient. after set `pure` to `true`, the page stucks and Firefox popup the alert box, saying the script keep running

Comment: You need to ensure `transform()` doesn't do unnecessary work. You could use the IterableDiffer (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html, https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/IterableDiffers-class.html) to check if the array has actually changed and if not, return a cached result from the previous call.